# SQL Server trigger inserting whole table rows, instead of new

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I m making a mistake somewhere but can't figure out.

Scenario is this:
Whenever a new row is inserted in table 'TestTrigger', the table TriggerInsert should get a value capturing time when a new row was inserted in TestTrigger.

The problem is, whenever the trigger hits, instead of just a new row, the whole table gets repopulated in TestTrigger, each time. I only want to capture, the new rows not the entire table getting inserted on each trigger.

Here is my trigger:

```
USE [irfaan]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[InsertTriggerTest] on [irfaan].[dbo].[TestTrigger]
--For Insert
After insert
as
INSERT into TriggerInsert (CurrTime, IOFNum) SELECT (GetDate()), SONum   FROM TestTrigger
```

Please assist where I am going wrong.

Comment: what database system are you using? Syntax varies between them and it is not possible to tell if your syntax is correct or not.

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at just the rows that were inserted, you must use the `Inserted` pseudo table - **not** the `dbo.TestTrigger` base table....

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.InsertTriggerTest
ON irfaan.dbo.TestTrigger
FOR INSERT
AS 
   INSERT INTO TriggerInsert (CurrTime, IOFNum) 
       SELECT GETDATE(), SONum   
       FROM Inserted
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Though it is still unclear to me, what does the Inserted table do?

Comment: @IrfaanWahid: the `Inserted` pseudo table contains **those rows that were inserted** by the statement that caused this trigger to be fired. [Read more about it at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables)

Comment: Thanks, understood.

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT query is returning all rows from your source table (TestTrigger).  Use the table **inserted** instead.  It will contain just the rows that are being inserted into TestTrigger instead of all of the rows as you are currently getting.

```
INSERT into TriggerInsert (CurrTime, IOFNum) SELECT (GetDate()), SONum   FROM Inserted
```